# Recaptcha::RecaptchaError in RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

For some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
Recaptcha::RecaptchaError in RegistrationsController#create
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known          

def create
if verify_recaptcha <--- this line is causing the error. 
 resource.save
     super
   else
     build_resource(sign_up_params)
```

Registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 def new
  super
 end

  def create
  if verify_recaptcha(:model => resource, :message => "Oh! It's error with reCAPTCHA!") && resource.save
      super
    else
      build_resource(sign_up_params)
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code."      
      flash.delete :recaptcha_error
      render :new
    end
  end

 protected
    def users_steps_path(resource)
        '/user_steps'
    end
end
```

registrations/new.html.erb form

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="styled email-input2">
            <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
            <%= devise_error_messages! %>
              <div><%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email", class: "email-input"  %>
              </div>
              <div><%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Username", class: "email-input"  %>
              </div>
              <div><%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Password", class: "email-input"  %>
              </div>
              <div><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Password confirmation", class: "email-input"  %>
              </div>
              <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeUQ_4SAAAAANicStPQ_OB68A-pr_EN3y3AF5UF"></div>
              <div><%= recaptcha_tags %></div>
          </div>

          <div class="get_motivated2">
            <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "get_motivated btn-danger" %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
```

routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

And the API keys are stored in my shell bash_profile file.

Any help here would be great!

p.s. The repcatcha doesn't show right away when I visit my regestrations/new.html.erb page, it only shows on refresh? How can we get it to display right away?

Comment: Fixed the recaptcha not showing up issue by adding data-no-turbolinks => true, as follows: <li><%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path, "data-no-turbolink" => true %></li>. However, initial error is still occurring upon submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for installation provides a default initializer like so:

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key  = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  config.private_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  config.proxy = 'http://myproxy.com.au:8080'
end
```

Delete the final line if you are not using a proxy:

```
config.proxy = 'http://myproxy.com.au:8080'
```